# Incompatible Types, Generics, <E>

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that returns an iterator over a set of `Integer` type elements, the class signature being (I've removed the access modifiers for brevity):

`class EvenIterator implements Iterator<Integer> { .... }`

The constructor is defined as follows:

```
public EvenIterator(Set<Integer> intSet) { .... }
```

The problem arises when I want to pass a collection of generics to the constructor. So, to flesh that out a bit. I have accessible, populated `HashSet<E> arbSet`.

I attempt to pass that set to the constructor; however, the compiler complains:

```
.... new EvenIterator(arbSet);
```

I am given this error (which I understand):

> The constructor GenericSet.EvenIterator(HashSet) is undefined

So, what I thought was a logical response was to say, "Great, I create a new HashSet of Integer types and pass arbSet to it's addAll() method":

```
.... new EvenIterator(new HashSet<Integer>().addAll(arbSet));
```

Of course, this doesn't solve the problem; however, there error gets a bit better (more specific):

> The method addAll( Collection < ? extends Integer > ) in the type AbstractCollection< Integer > is not applicable for the arguments (HashSet< E >)

Great! But, what do I do about it without haing to change - or overload - the constructor for `EvenIterator`? Is there an eloquent way to accomplish this? Or, will it involve something as unpleasant as iterating over the generic list and pulling out the `Integer`s - given that all members are `Integer` type?

Comment: You have defined your constructor to accept a set of Integers. Why do you think it should be able to accept a set of something arbitrary? For example, a set of Cars or a set of Vegetables?

Comment: `new EventIterator(new HashSet<Integer>())` works with constructor `EvenIterator(Set<Integer>)`. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); or at least show your `arbSet` declaration

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes, that is plain. I understand that. The problem is that the situation allows for the `Set<E>` to contain things other than `Integer` types; however, if not, I need to be able treat the `Set` as a `Set` of Integer types. I ain't the architect.

Comment: Then describe what the "situation" is exactly, and what the design constraint here (what the "architect" wants) are. What does your iterator do, what are you populating your set with, and why does it have to fit into this particular constructor. Please expand your question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am not sure that's necessary? The question stands on its own, fine. Your curiosity about design decisions is mine; however, "why" something is the case isn't relevant, here. It just is and - unfortunately - it's unalterable. The question could be further reduced, certainly: How do I cast a generic type `HashSet<E>` to a `Set<Integer>` - that's the heart of the question, everything else is paltry.

Comment: If you don't expand on the design decisions, we can't supply an alternative for you that will work within your constraints. You might *think* the proper solution is a way to cast the set, but I suggest that it usually isn't and may result in runtime errors and problems debugging at a later stage. This is not "personal curiosity", it's understanding your constraints given that you are trying to avoid what appears to be the correct way to do things.

Comment: You are trying to salvage a bad design IMO. If the arbSet has integers only in it just make it a set of integers. if not then the constructor which expects integers anyway will blow - so ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I thoroughly agree.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I stand corrected. Notice I also voted to close the question. Thank you for your patience and willingness to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you are trying to do an unsafe cast.  What you want to do *may* produce `ClassCastException`s at runtime. It is up to you (as the developer of the program) to ensure that this doesn't happen or these exceptions are properly handled. That is why you are getting the compile error.

You can avoid the compile error by using a cast, like this:

```
new EvenIterator((Set<Integer>) arbSet);
```

This will cause a compile time warning because the cast is still unsafe.

If you are sure that this unsafe cast really isn't a problem in your code, you can add:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

to the containing method declaration.

But, fundamentally, you should know why you need that cast before you actually ignore the warnings.

---

**EDIT** Here is the snippet that I have that compiles, warning-free:

```
class EvenIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    public EvenIterator(Set<Integer> intSet) { }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() { }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<?> arbSet = null;
        new EvenIterator((Set<Integer>) arbSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the cast and get "Cannot cast from HashSet<E> to Set<Integer>" as the error.

Comment: @Andrew: please reply to the comment above

Comment: @Thomas , not sure why you say it doesn't work. Check this: https://ideone.com/mhhC9x , which shows that above solution works

Comment: @manzur Yeah,  i have no idea what is going on : `Set<Integer> is = (Set<Integer>) new HashSet<E>();` is causing an red-line error.

Comment: @Thomas , how do you define E ?

Comment: @manzur what do you mean? Shouldn't that code stand independently?

Comment: @Thomas, see the code snippet I added.

Answer (score 0):

Well it simply has to be a HashSet of Integers not any type E.

```
HashSet<Integer> arbSet
```

should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably `HashSet<E extends Integer>`. If this is not an option then the design is wrong - it just defies the purpose of generics. If the constructor needs and expects Integers then very rightly Java won't allow you to pass a collection of arbitrary elements in - and the workaround with addAll is equally unacceptable.

Re: The constructor GenericSet.EvenIterator(HashSet) is undefined

This is because while HashSet is a subclass of Set `(Hash)Set<E>` is not a subclass of `Set<Integer>`